# Yosemite reset password that lost

Tags: mac, osx-yosemite

I pressed command + r and clicked power button and release it (command + r) when I saw apple logo. I tried several but the mac doesn't enter recovery mode. How to reset password in yosemite?

Comment: Which password? Your OS X user account password? (The instructions might be different if you're dealing with a lost **firmware** password.) Do you have another user account with Admin privileges that you can log into?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're timing the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> thing wrong, try holding down <kbd>option</kbd> at boot to get to the boot picker. See if your recovery drive shows up there. If it does, select it and boot from it. If you don't get into the boot picker, you were timing your key-holding-down thing wrong.

Are you using a Bluetooth keyboard? They lose connection at reboot and have to re-establish it, and if you're already holding down keys when they re-establish their link, they'll ignore those keys. In order to successfully use boot-time key chords on a Bluetooth keyboard, press them down *as the sound of the boot chime trails off*. Assuming you have a Mac that still has a boot chime.

If you have figured out how to time your boot-time key chords and you just don't have a working recovery partition on your system, you might be able to use Internet Recovery (if your machine is a 2012 or later model). To do that, hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at boot. You'll need either an Ethernet or Wi-Fi connection to the Internet.

If that still doesn't work, try this:

1. Boot into Single User Mode by holding down <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> at boot.
2. Follow the on-screen instructions to run a filesystem check and then remount the boot drive as read/write. It's something like this:

```
    fsck -fy
    mount -uw /
```

3. Start the Open Directory daemon so the password database becomes editable:

   `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist`
4. Reset the password of the user in question:

   `passwd` *username*
5. Exit Single User Mode to boot back into full OS X:

   `exit`